# Using Nodemailer with Google OAuth

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, nodemailer

I'm trying to send emails using nodemailer while my site is deployed on Heroku.

The only thing that seems to work for me is using Google OAuth.

The problem I'm having is that it only works until the access token is changed. On the Google OAuth Playground, I used my own `clientId` and `clientSecret` in exchange for a `refreshToken` and `accessToken`. It generated that for me and also an expiration of 3600 seconds. It works during that time but not after. Can this be prevented from expiring or is there another way to make it work with Heroku?

Nodemailer on server code:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'beyondutraining@gmail.com',
    clientId: keys.clientID,
    clientSecret: keys.clientSecret,
    refreshToken: keys.refreshToken,
    accessToken: keys.accessToken
  }
})
```

error after access token expires:

```
{ Error: Invalid status code 400
at ClientRequest.req.on.res 
(/app/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/fetch/index.js:221:23)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:543:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:112:17)
at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:440:20)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
type: 'FETCH',
sourceUrl: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
code: 'EAUTH',
command: 'AUTH XOAUTH2' }
```

[Github source code](http://Willdta/React-Shgithub.comopping-Cart)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Google Auth, here's the deal : the token is ought to expire in atmost an hour ( 1 hour = 3600 s ). This is the default behavior - you cannot change the expiry threshold.

However, at your end, you may write a piece of code to trigger the fetching of OAuth every one hour from the time of trigger. And then you may circulate the refreshed value across the code.

I am not sure why you are sending both refresh and access tokens. You might wish to send only one of them. While access tokens expire in at most an hour, the refresh token doesn't - it is long lived. Refresh token rather refreshes the access token for you : so you don't have to trigger that every time.

Have a look over here : [OAuth2 with Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/)

But, if you wish to proceed with the `access_token`, you may have a glance the following subsection : [Custom OAuth Handling](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#custom-handling).

Maybe you can utilise the value of the parameter `renew`, based on which you may write the logic needed to generate a new access token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I'm having with this solution is that if I don't give Heroku an `access_token` it won't send the email but if I do then it does (until it expires). Do you might know why this is? The `refresh_token` works without the `access_token` on localhost but both are needed when deployed to Heroku.

Comment: @RogerFedFan It would be great if you could share the source ( or atleast the structure, if source code sharing isn't possible ) of invocation and deployment over the Heroku, so that I could come up with reasons on the track.

Comment: I went ahead and added the error on Heroku logs. Do you want a Github source of my project as well?

Comment: @RogerFedFan Please share the errors that you might see in the logs. If that's okay, you might share your GitHub source post that.

Comment: Ok I went ahead and added both to my original post. Thanks for taking the time to examine them!

Comment: @RogerFedFan You might as well want to have a look at this : https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#troubleshooting . Are you sure you're using the correct scope for OAuth2 ?

Comment: I think I am. I'm using `https:mail.google.com/` I just can't a way to make it work with just using the refresh token. Access token is always needed with heroku.

Comment: @RogerFedFan You may as well wish to go ahead with this : [ https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps ]. Let us know if turning it off helps.

Comment: I feel it is related to the Heroku configuration then. There's something that's blocking your connection / signin to gmail from either end. Could be that you have to whitelist / set up correct origins / URLs in the Google Dev whilst creating tokens ?

Comment: I'm open to trying to do so. Is there any resources or links I can follow to do so?